# How can I search in the comments?

Tags: versioning, visual-sourcesafe

In my company (as in most) source code modifications are described in so-called "tickets", which have a unique ID for reference purposes. When somebody checks in a file, that ID is entered in the "comment" field.

Recently somebody has checked in a file, but I don't know which one. I do know the ID, so by querying the comments I should be able to find that file.

How can I query the comments of my Visual SourceSafe system?

For your information, I have no problem checking the files/database where SourceSafe keeps its information internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command line with `ss.exe`, there is no built-in way to search comments *only* (to be sure, I actually went through all relevant [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/003ssz4z(v=vs.80)) and [commands options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hsxzf2az(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#see-also)).

However, you can combine `history` command with PowerShell's `Find-String`:

```
PS C:\Programs Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe>$env:SSDIR = "path\to\srcsafe.ini\dir"
PS C:\Programs Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe>.\ss history $/path/to/desired/directory/or/file | Select-String -Pattern yourid -Context 10,1
```

Notes:

- `Context 10,1` gets you the preceding 10 lines and succeeding 1 line, so that you'll see the matched file details.
- For more advanced usage utilizing `history`, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853155/parse-the-source-safe-history-output-and-run-the-diff-command).
- I guess you can also use external tools, like [VssReporter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4709/VssReporter-2-1-A-Visual-SourceSafe-reporting-tool) (but I have no experience with that).

Comment: I just discovered that this command does not show the files, which are currently checked out. Do you know about a parameter which shows those files too?

Comment: I'll be able to check this out next week, I'll let you know.